# Julia: Macros, Expressions and Meta.parse

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

All these following lines of code are Julia expressions:

```
x = 10
1 + 1
println("hi")
```

if you want to pass an expression to a macro, it works like this. Macro foo just returns the given expression, which will be executed:

```
macro foo(ex)
  return ex
end

@foo println("yes") # prints yes

x = @foo 1+1
println(x) # prints 2
```

If you want to convert a string into an expression, you can use Meta.parse():

```
string = "1+1"
expr = Meta.parse(string)
x = @foo expr
println(x) # prints 1 + 1
```

But, obviously, the macro treats expr as a symbol. What am i getting wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Macro `hygiene` is important "macros must ensure that the variables they introduce in their returned expressions do not accidentally clash with existing variables in the surrounding code they expand into." There is a section in the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.2-dev/manual/metaprogramming/#Hygiene-1). It is easiest just to show a simple case:

```
macro foo(x)
    return :($x)
end
```

When you enter an ordinary expression in the REPL, it is evaluated immediately.  To suppress that evaluation, surround the expression with `:( )`.

```
julia> 1 + 1
2
julia> :(1 + 1)
:(1 + 1)
# note this is the same result as you get using Meta.parse
julia> Meta.parse("1 + 1")
:(1 + 1)
```

So, `Meta.parse` will convert an appropriate string to an expression.  And if you `eval` the result, the expression will be evaluated. Note that printing a simple expression removes the outer `:( )`

```
julia> expr = Meta.parse("1 + 1")
:(1 + 1)
julia> print(expr)
1 + 1
julia> result = eval(expr)
2
```

Usually, macros are used to manipulate things before the usual evaluation of expressions; they are syntax transformations, mostly.  Macros are performed before other source code is compiled/evaluated/executed.

Rather than seeking a macro that evaluates a string as if it were typed directly into the REPL (without quotes), use this function instead.

```
evalstr(x::AbstractString) = eval(Meta.parse(x))
```

While I do not recommend this next macro, it is good to know the technique.
A macro named `<name>_str` is used like this `<name>"<string contents>"` :

```
julia> macro eval_str(x)
          :(eval(Meta.parse($x)))
      end

julia> eval"1 + 1"
2
```

(p.s. do not reuse Base function names as variable names, use `str` not `string`)

Please let me know if there is something I have not addressed.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey, but still i'm not sure if i got it! To boil down my question: What is the difference between the expression `1+1` and `Meta.parse("1+1")`? because `@foo 1+1` and `@foo Meta.parse("1+1")` will not give the same result.

Comment: If i put `println(typeof(ex))` inside the macro, in both cases it will print `Expr`...

Comment: hm, ok `expr = Meta.eval("1+1"); @foo epxr` is not the same as `@foo Meta.eval("1+1")`.

Comment: `Meta.eval` is really not what you want.  `eval` does essentially the same thing and is clearer.  Use it instead.

 `str = "1 + 1"; eval(str) == str; expr = Meta.parse(str); val = eval(expr);` and so
`@foo(str) == str; @foo(expr) == expr; @foo(val) == val` (as it should be).

Comment: Ah, sorrrrrry, this was a typo! i meant: `expr = Meta.parse("1+1"); @foo epxr` is not the same as @foo Meta.parse("1+1"). I'm not sure if we just talk at cross purposes. I try again to state my question more clearly: What operation do i have to apply on a string, so that it will be treated exactly the same as a "plain" expression as `1+1`?

Comment: `evalstr(x) = eval(Meta.parse(str))`